# Why my ctag function jump extremely slow?

Tags: vim, tags, ctags

---

## Important update 22,July,2014

**I found that long time consuming jump only happens when Jump to Modules and classes in other directories. And jump to function or method in other modules in other directories is fast(costs 1 or 2 seconds)**

---

I'm new to ctags, so I tried find some tutorials online.

I read most of them, and find this one sounds more official: [source_forge ctag faq](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/faq.html#1)

But I find follow the method 3 on this tutorial：building tag files in each leaf node directory and a non-static tag file in the main directory. But I can't jump in leaf nodes between its own different modules. I can only jump from the main directory to leaf nodes module functions.

Anyway, I found another tutorial:[benoithamelin's personal tutorial](http://benoithamelin.tumblr.com/post/15101202004/using-vim-exuberant-ctags-easy-source-navigation)
. And I build a huge tag in the main directory, including 4700+ tag lines. by using

```
ctags -R *
```

Hey, friends. I find I can jump now. Except, for some jumps, I need to wait for about 30 seconds. That's unbearable, and for other view tags, I can switch to them quickly in 1 or 2 seconds. What's wrong here? How can I fix it?

Below is a tree graph of my directory structure:

```
my_project
├── tags  # my tag is here
├── lib
│   ├── dir1
│   │   └── sub_dir1
│   ├── dir2
│   ├── dir3
│   └── dir4
├── logics
│   ├── dir1
│   ├── dir2
│   │   └──sub_dir1
│   ├── dir3
│   └── dir4
├── models
└── views
```

- The symptom is you deadlocked at the vim edit interface, unable to type any command, until the function jump complete, it cost nearly 30 seconds.
- I'm using Exuberant Ctags 5.9, Vim 7.4 and Ubuntu 14.04 with wmii
- The my_project directory I tag-searched is a share directory between the Windows7 main operating system and VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04 operating system
- I'm also using taglist, but when I edited a file in the main directory which contains the tag file, I didn't see functions in sub-directories such as logics appears in taglist(:TlistToogle).
- And when the function jumping is in the deadlock searching status, even vim /path/to/my/file would be quite slow

Comment: I have about 7000 with no slow down. Have you cleaned up all of the old tag files you generated?

Comment: Could it be something wrong? it was in a git directory. I think it's extremely wild. I use ctrl + ] to jump

Comment: @FDinoff, I cleaned all those tags and leave only the main big tag, and the problem still exists, it's so wired, the key point is it can do it successfully, but with 30 seconds delays, !!!

Comment: Copy your code base over your local machine and you will most certainly see a big speed boost.

Comment: @romain, it's local, just virtual machine, not remote.

Comment: For a sanity check can you reproduce the slowness when using a minimal vimrc and no plugins runnings

Comment: @FDinoff, I disabled them, and still the same, the symptom is you deadlocked at the vim edit interface, unable to type any command, until the function jump complete.

Comment: Again, see if moving your project over to the virtual machine (not a shared directory) changes anything. Also, the correct command is `$ ctags -R .`.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add this here as an answer as it was buried in a comment from @sylvain:

```
set tags=tags
set path=.
```

Added to my vimrc resolved this problem for me, running Neovim 0.2. In case someone needs this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism by which vim finds a tag and jumps to it is, roughly, this:

```
foreach tagfile in &tags
    search for $tag in $tagfile
    if found:
        get filename from $tagfile
        foreach dir in &path:
             if $filename in $dir:
                 open $filename to $tag
```

With that in mind, there are 2 points at which I think you could be hitting a delay:

- Opening `$tagname`
- Checking for `$filename` in `$dir`

simply because both of these involve filesystem access.

Check the contents of both the `&tags` and `&path` options (with `:set tags` and `:set path`) and make sure that there's nothing in either of those that sits on a networked or slow drive.

Comment: Didn't try it, but don't want to waste the bounty to the system. I guess you spend efforts on this issue, so you deserve this.

Comment: Now the method jump isn't a problem, only module jump and very few method jump still very slow.

Comment: I added  `set tags=tags` and `set path=.` and it solved the issue for me. Using ctrlptjump helped me to get faster jump to tags too.